# Merge 'alarm' and 'alarms' tags

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

Don't know which should win; they both have three questions.

- [alarm](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alarm)
- [alarms](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alarms)

I lean toward the singular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moved alarms to alarm.  Vote on synonym here: https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/alarm/synonyms

Answer (score 1):

Isn't the rule of thumb that tags should be plural? Wikipedia uses [that method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Categorization):

```
Set categories are named after a class (usually in the plural).
```

Eg, if we're talking about "New York City" the tag is not "city" but "cities" -- because the tag would be applied to "Paris", "Chicago" etc.

Just so for "apps" "alarms" "keyboards" etc.

I may have followed this rule inconsistently, myself. *Mea Culpa.*

Comment: I think it depends. For instance, [contact] as a tag makes no sense (IMNSHO), but [contacts] does.

Comment: well, that's my point -- [alarm] as a tag makes no sense: as singular, it would be applied to THAT QUESTION AND ALARM INSTANCE ONLY; as plural, it would be for many instances of alarms and alarm-related issues. [handsets] refers to all, [HTC_Desire] refers to one specific type (but all instances of that specific type). Thus [alarms] and [proximity_alarm] are distinct.

Comment: I agree with using plurals.  I find it useful to prepend "On the subject of" to the tag when deciding.  "On the subject of alarms" makes sense, "On the subject of alarm" does not.  Some exceptions are device names because of an implied "the" ("On the subject of [the] droid") or when the primary sense of the word/phrase is not a noun.